# Export test results from Test Explorer visual studio 2013

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver, tfs, mstest

I want to find a solution to export my test results from test explorer to **TFS** or any other format like excel. I saw some posts bases on **.trx** file. In test results folder of my project I have a folder generated each time I run a test with 2 sub folders **IN** and **OUT**. The **IN** folder is always empty and **OUT** folder contains **AgentRestart.dat** file. If I run my whole test suite I can only see number of passed and failed tests in Test Explorer. To find out result of each test case and store I need to select on test case one at a time and copy paste to word. I'm looking for a better solution.

I'm using unit test project with MS Test.

Can some one help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to export test results from VS UI. However, you can use [VSTest.Console.exe command-line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) to achieve it:

```
vstest.console.exe myTestFile.dll /Logger:trx
```

If you want to To publish test results to Team Foundation Server, use TfsPublisher:

```
/logger:TfsPublisher;
Collection=<team project url>;
BuildName=<build name>;
TeamProject=<team project name>;
[;Platform=<Defaults to “Any CPU”>]
[;Flavor=<Defaults to “Debug”>]
[;RunTitle=<title>]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I couldn't find .trx file in my project folder. Regarding TFS, can you give more details. I'm not very good at TFS.

Comment: Command vstest.console.exe myTestFile.dll /Logger:trx will generate a .trx file, you may have a try. Regarding publishing to TFS, you may take a look at this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner/

Comment: Thank you so much I did get the .trx file. I struggled for this for months thank you so so much. I just have one question, Is it possible to store the .trx file to our preferred location. At the moment it is creating Test Results folder in my dll location. Can we change the path for the trx. Can you please help with this? Thanks

Comment: /logger:trx logs results into a Visual Studio Test Results File (TRX) by default. No option to specify the output path, sorry.

Comment: I had a Test Results folder separately in project level created by VS UI. But when I'm running them through command line, it is creating in Bin>Debug folder. That's k I finally found a solution, just wanted to confirm whether we can change the folder. Anyway thank you so much for the answer. Thanks for your reply.