# Visual Studio: Test Explorer Copying Title names of Unit Tests into Flat File CSV or Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core, test-explorer

We are creating a Unit test project for our C# Net core project. How do I copy the names of all tests, and if they passed succeeded/or failed into an CSV or flat file excel spreadsheet from Test Explorer. When I do right click and copy, it pastes it into a not good looking format. Again, just looking for tests names and results from Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

[Export test results from Test Explorer visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052807/export-test-results-from-test-explorer-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not mentioning automated way or using codes, you can use group summary window and it will give result nice way, test name and status. Use Copy all button.

[image]

Results will be like this
[image]

Or you can generate trx file, which contains test results. It is a xml file and you can read that generate your excel file.

Go to this folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
```

And Run below command.

```
vstest.console.exe yourFullProjectPath\YourTestProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\YourTest.dll /logger:trx;LogFileName=C:\Users\Codes\testresult.trx
```

Comment: I meant by by configuring or save result file to auto. You can use mstest or second method I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of tests in Test Explorer, create a playlist of the tests (which is formatted as an xml file), then open it in Excel.  The data will be separated into numerous columns corresponding to each of the xml file labels, the last column being the test name.

Comment: This however does not provide information on whether the tests completed successfully or not.